# Camel readLockMinLength=0 creates a 0 length file even if data exists

Tags: apache-camel

I tried to fix zero length file to process by setting `readLockMinLength=0`. All Good, zero byte files are getting processed.

Now the problem is I have very huge file(around 2 GB). In my destination I receive two files :

1. Actual file with data
2. Actual file with Zero byte

**From Route**    include=.*.*&delay=20000&readLockCheckInterval=20000&readLockTimeout=60000&readLock=changed&**readLockMinLength=0**&readLockLoggingLevel=OFF&delete=true"

My filename has timestamp.
I am not sure why it create's additional zero byte file but when I remove readLockMinLength=0. It never creates zero byte file.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And can you be more clear what you mean with 2 files with data and 0 byte, eg you cannot have 2 files with the same name, so this is confusing.

Comment: Do you get any readlock warnings when you raise the `readLockLoggingLevel `?

Comment: Camel 2.19. As the destination location to copy the file contains timestamp(date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss) so I received two files in the destination with different timestamp.

Comment: @burki in production DEBUG is disabled so no logs with warning. Also In my route I set readLockLoggingLevel=OFF

Answer (score 0):

Your **polling frequency is 20 seconds**, the check interval for the read lock is the same and the read lock timeout is 60 seconds.

Is it possible that **multiple directory pollings interfere with each other**?

Have you tried to raise the `delay` to more than 60 seconds, so that the next polling starts after any read lock stuff of the current polling?

**EDIT** due to new information that same application runs on 4 nodes.

There is a warning in the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) where the property `readLock` is explained:

> Warning: most of the read lock strategies are not suitable for use in clustered mode. That is, you cannot have multiple consumers attempting to read the same file in the same directory. In this case, the read locks will not function reliably.

In such situations we run only one instance and use a watchdog to monitor the process. If the process dies the watchdog is restarting it automatically.

Comment: 1) You are right polling is set to 20 sec. That's the business requirement.   2)  I set readlock due to cluster environment. Same application running on four nodes.